# Decode 2d data matrix barcode in HTML/JavaScript (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, barcode-scanner, datamatrix

**Context:** I need to scan a data matrix barcode with the camera of my android mobile phone. I access the camera over html5 and got the picture into a canvas element.

**Approach:** I can't find a javascript library for scanning a picture to decode a 2D data matrix code. Actually i call the ZXing App and copy and go backt etc. So i'm not happy with this laborious solution.

**Question:** Somebody knows a javascript library for decoding 2D data matrix codes? Or maybe an easy solution by using another app like ZXing / Goggles and get the result of the scan automatically back in JS?!

I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: Just curious if you've made any progress on this. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find any library?

Comment: [STRICH](https://strich.io) is a 1D/2D barcode scanning library for JavaScript and supports Data Matrix. There is a free demo you can try. Disclaimer: I am the author.